# Get an EventArgument with .PerformClick()

Tags: c#

I try to create dynamic Buttons and simulate a Mouseclick without importing Dlls by using .PerformClick.

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < save.Count; i++)
{
    Button tempButtonForClick = new Button();
    tempButtonForClick.Location = save[i].SaveRegion.Location;
    Cursor.Position = save[i].SaveRegion.Location;
    tempButtonForClick.Size = save[i].SaveRegion.Size;
    tempButtonForClick.Click += new EventHandler(MainPanelClicks);
    MainPanel.Controls.Add(tempButtonForClick);
    tempButtonForClick.PerformClick();
    ...
}
```

The Problem is, that i get an empty EventArgs with that method. Is there any way to get a "normal" EventArgument?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `EventArgs` itself doesn't have any useful information - what information were you expecting to see?

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF?

Comment: As Jon Skeet says, the "normal" `EventArgs` does not contain any information. So it can be blank...

Comment: Im using Forms. I expect to get the Locationdata, Delta and the pressed Mousebutton of the click .

Comment: The Click event does not include those in its EventArgs, normal or not. You're probably thinking of one of the mouse-related events, which have MouseEventArgs available.

Comment: The Button's Click event passes a MouseEventArgs instance supercasted to EventArgs most of the time. MouseEventArgs extends EventArgs. It is not the case that **every** event raising of the Click event will pass a MouseEventArgs, but whenever the user clicks the button it **will**.

Comment: Thanks you, that helped me a lot to understand my wrong idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really encourage you to do it like so, but if you really really want it, here it goes.
(The best thing would be to create an extra layer of control and trigger things from that layer -- Action Manager kind of layer).

First, create yourself a nice little extension method container class like:

```
public static class ButtonExtensions {

    // Button indirectly extends Control
    // Control has a protected method: protected void OnClick(EventArgs e);
    // you can't call it directly, you need to do it via reflection
    private static readonly MethodInfo controlsOnClickMethod = typeof(Control).GetMethod("OnClick", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    // Although the second parameter of the Button.Click event
    // is syntactically: EventArgs
    // at runtime, it is usually a MouseEventArgs
    // so that's what we're going to send it
    public static void PerformClickEx(this Button @this, MouseEventArgs args) {
        ButtonExtensions.controlsOnClickMethod.Invoke(@this, new object[] { args });
    }

}
```

and how do you use this ? Really easy:

```
public class Foo {

    private Button someButton;

    public void Bar() {
        this.someButton.PerformClickEx(new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Right, 1, 100, 100, 2));
    }
}
```

and you get the much desired, non-empty, full of mouse information EventArgs (which is actually a MouseEventArgs) :)